# Greater than the size of a certain area postgres

Tags: postgresql, comparison-operators

I have a simple table with site_names and site_area sizes. Now I want to now which sites are larger than the site called 'bullepolder' in Postgres. The site_area is 14 ha. So I can use:

```
SELECT site_name, site_area 
FROM site 
WHERE site_area >= '14'
```

But it is kind of a hastle to look up al the sizes before I can query and if the area size changes the query isn't suitable anymore. Is there an easier way? Can site_name be linked to site_area somehow?

Comment: Please explain. What is a site called 'bullepolder'?

Comment: Unrelated, but: if `site_area` is a number, you should compare it to one. `'14'` is string constant, `14` is a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a sub-select.

```
select site_name, site_are
from site
where site_area > (select s2.site_area
                   from site s2
                   where s2.site_name = 'bulledpolder');
```

The above assumes that `site_name` is unique. If it's not, you will get an error.